# Installer for VS Express 2015 C# winform project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have developed a Winforms project using C# and .NET 4.5 in VS Express 2015 as front end and Firebird SQL as backend. Now I want to create an installer for the project so that it could be installed easily on client computers.

I have searched the internet for 'setup & deployment' but all those articles are old and they all explain how to create installer using older version of Visual Studio like VS 2008, VS 2010 etc. In the current version of VS, no such facility is present.

Now my question is: how do I create an installer for my projects? Can anyone suggest me any FREE installer creator that I can use for my project?

Comment: Look at the [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: There is also a VS extension that provides support for Visual Studio Installer Projects in Visual Studio 2015. Have a look at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randoms is correct - there is an add-in installer extension for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (which is free)

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

and it hasn't changed much at all - articles you find will generally still apply.